# alternative of if else-if else statement c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to expand my knowledge of conditional statements in C++

```
if (condition){
return 0;
}

if else (condition A && condition B) {
//
}

else {
//
}
```

in this multiple conditonal state, what would be a good alternative? 
Obviously because of `condition A` && `condition B` on `if else` statement, I can't use `switch` statement?

Comment: I believe you mean `else if`.  But, what is the reasoning behind needing to do it differently?  Sounds like the perfect situation for an `else if` construct...

Comment: It all depends on what your conditions are. As written, since you have a return statement in the first if you don't need that "if else", you can just do another if.

Comment: Also, as you have a `return` statement in the first `if` block, you don't need the `else` in the following `else if`.

Comment: What do your conditions look like? Does each condition compare to some numerical value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what would be a good alternative?

Shouldn't matter if no *good* alternative is *better* than what you already have.

(Ignoring the apparent `if else` error) Your shown control flow appears to be quite minimal (and therefore good) representation. There is no code duplication, and no repetitive structure that could be further exploited.